# STM32F429 Timer triggered USART DMA transfer issue

Tags: timer, dma, stm32f4discovery, usart

This is my first post at this forum.
I am developing a MIDI sequencer device based on a STM32F429DISCOVERY board running at stock 180MHz. In order to send midi messages the USART1 is configured for 31250 bauds and the appropriate DMA is configured to transfer a 3 byte array stored in ram to the USART. I was doing tests of even timing of sending of midi messages, by configuring the Timer 4 update interrupt, within the service routine of which I am enabling the memory-to-peripheralUSART1 DMA operation. This gives me a periodic sending of a 3 byte message over the USART1 peripheral.

Everything works great and with correct frequency and correct data, but i have a small issue which i have been researching for few days now and have not been able to correct. To make things clearer, within the timer interrupt routine I set a led on the discovery (RG13) to momentarily blink and connected 1 channel of an oscilloscope to the led pin. The second channel of the oscilloscope is connected to the USART TX pin. Now, when the code is executed, i can see the led pulse on the oscilloscope's CH1,  followed by the USART serial data on the CH2. But for some reason the time between the led pulse and the beginning of the serial data transfer fluctuates with every sending of the data. It increments with every sending, going from around 1uS to around 30uS, and then jumps back to 1.
I noticed that if i slightly change the USART baudrate, the time fluctuation between the pulse and the data sending changes in pattern, going faster or slower and with longer or shorter range.
I have tried resetting all the apropriate flags from USART as well as DMA, have tried to disable/enable the timer, played with interrupt priorities, but nothing has worked to get rid of the time fluctuation.
As you can imagine, the stability of this is crucial for a MIDI sequencer hardware application as it bases the timing of the musical events, which must be rock solid.
I have also tried using the USART by itself without DMA, manually sending every byte,  basically same results. Interrupt driven USART TX exhibited likewise results.
The only thing which seemed to work to get rid of the time fluctuation of USART TX response is, before every sending operation to deinitialize USART and the DMA modules and reinitialize them again. This seemed to give a stable operation but inserts a long delay between the timer interrupt and the actual sending of the data over the USART, which is unacceptable.

If anyone has any thoughts on this or have done anything similar, I need an advice on where to look at.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best regards, 
Konstantin

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Most "regulars" have a list of tags they monitor closely, and none of yours look particularly common... Tagging with an operating system or programming language will probably bring your question more attention. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Even based on your detailed description, there are various possibilities for errors, so best I can do is guess:

Maybe just one of the TIM setting is just slightly wrong: What about the timer's auto-reload register (TIM4_ARR)?

The period setting must be just one unit *lower than* the desired transmission period divided by the (possibly prescaled) clock period (see details upcounting/downcounting spec).

Now, if the reload value were just *equal* to the value instead, the second trigger would be late by one tiny period, the third trigger twice as much and so on (which may look like what you described). 
This "ramp of delays" would then rise until the unwanted delay sums up to one UART bit period (which happens to be 32uS for 31250 bauds, quite near to the "around 30uS" you described). The next trigger would then just fit for the neighbouring UART bit cycle (without much delay).

Comparing this hypothesis with your other findings...

- Changing the UART baud rate would preserve the fundamental error, but the duration of the irritating delay changes. It can appear to change its sign ("faster or slower"), depending on the beat characteristics between the (actual) TIM period and the UART bit period. => OK
- Changing the event processing from DMA to IRQ handler wouldn't change much about the problem but only the "phase" of the initial delay (by the time the CPU needs to execute a different ST library function). => OK
- Disabling and re-enabling the UART might have changed the behaviour because the UART clock might re-synchronize newly with the underlying bus clock (APB2 for USART2), so the delay after the TIM trigger would appear constant, and you wouldn't notice fluctuations. => OK

Comment: With my answer, I'm a little bit late for the party, but maybe you find your old code somewhere a corner on your attic, or it helps somebody else...